# Redis errors in Kube cluster

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, redis, kubernetes-helm, redisson

When deploying to an environment in k8s cluster this is the error I'm getting in Jenkins. I've checked my config file also don't see anything weird there. The below test cases fail and the cause points to DNS resolution. The unit tests are just the endpoint tested via `mockMvc`.

I'm not sure how to put my finger where in K8s its failing but the stack trace points to something  in the cluster not being traceable.

Anyway I can debug what is going wrong or ask the concerned person what needs to be investigated in the cluster?

````
public RedissonClient redisson(@Value("classpath:redission/redisson-dev.yaml") final Resource configFile)
      throws IOException {
   final var config = Config.fromYAML(configFile.getInputStream());
   return Redisson.create(config);
}```

`ava.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException at ConstructorResolver.java:800
            Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at ConstructorResolver.java:658
                Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException at SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185
                    Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException at DnsResolveContext.java:1014`
````

Answer (score 0):

> Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException

Tells us that the host can't be resolved.